# Leave SPDIF enabled

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, mint, spdif

I have [optical S/PDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF) output as my primary sound output.  Problem is, it takes about 1/2 second between when sound starts and when my output device starts the playback.  I assume it is because the audio receiving side (a Logitech Z-5500) needs this time to detect the signal type.  That means I miss the first 1/2 second of audio.  Mostly a nuisance, especially for messages which have a short ping to indicate incoming messages.

One work around is to leave on music, or play audio at a frequency above hearing range (use Audacity to create a 30 kHz tone at low-volume).

Is there a better solution such as a configuration value that doesn't disable the S/PDIF signal when there is no audio being played?

Comment: I assume you're using Linux Mint?

Comment: @ThomasWard Correct.  But it does (did) the same thing in Ubuntu.